# Pygame window can not be closed on a Mac problem

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I have made a python program that uses Pygame. For some reason, I can't close the window when pressing the red cross. I tried using Command+Q but it doesn't work as well. I have to quit idle (my python interpreter) to close the window. Is there any other way to make the window close by pressing the red 'x' at the top right-hand corner?

My code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
while 1:     
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Try running the file through the command line by just double-clicking the .py file rather than executing it from idle

Comment: @Pzet Running from the command line works but I need a way to run the program from idle since it is in the requirements of a task I am working on. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you're running it in IDLE use 'raise SystemExit' rather than 'sys.exit()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pygame window can be closed properly if you use a different python interpreter. Try using pycharm, you can close pygame windows using pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

You should just force quit the window or run another program to close the window. When you run a different program, the window should close.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
while True:     
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your code is the same as mine. `while True` is the same as ` while 1`, they are both forever loops. The window made by this code also can't be closed.